Приветствую вас знатоки. Подскажите кто знает. Как в unity передавать в метод массив любого типа?
К примеру есть простой код.. Какую сигнатуру метода надо прописать чтобы можно было передавать методу не только Image[],но и Text[], по отдельности.
Image[] imageBoxOpen = new Image[3];
Text[] textCollect = new Text[2];

 private void OnEnable()
    {
        Metod(imageBoxOpen,1);
    }

private void Metod(Image[] all ,int index)
    {
        foreach (var item in all)
        {
            item.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
    }



Нагуглил решение, но не понимаю его. Подскажите в чем туплю..

 public void Test()
    {
        Metod2(imageBoxOpen,2);
    }

 private void Metod2 <T>(T[] all, int index) // Методу все нравиться 
    {
        foreach (var item in all)
        {
            item.gameObject.SetActive(false);  // А тут доступа к gameobject нет ошибка. 
        }
    }


Ошибка CS1061  'T' does not contain a definition for 'gameObject' and no accessible extension method 'gameObject' accepting a first argument of type 'T' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

"А тут доступа к gameobject нет ошибка" --- какая ошибка? Как вызываешь метод?

Вызываю просто из другого метода

Гениальный ответ. Вопрос был "как" а не "откуда"

Методом Test в котором вызываю Metod2( и передаю ему тут массив и индекс по условиям сигнатуры метода )

Может ты всё же кодом покажешь?

Возможно, что то не обновилось но в коде это показано.

На всякий случай добавлю и в комментарий, но выше в коде это есть public void Test()
{
Metod2(imageBoxOpen,2);
}

"Гениальный ответ. Вопрос был "как" а не "откуда"", вопрос был вообще не в этом, вопрос был в массиве, который может иметь любой тип; т.е. вопрос не в "как" и не в "откуда"; вопрос - а что такое массив любого типа?

@Александр прочитайте пожалуйста про обобщённые типы (generic types); например на сайте майкрософта https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.12.php или метанита https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.12.php

Спасибо, обязательно почитаю

@Александр извините, вот верная ссылка на майкрософт https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/generics/

Всем огромное спасибо.

Ограничение универсального типа не позволяет использовать, как аргумент типы не наследуемые от указанного и соответственно происходит привидение T типа к указанному. gameObject это свойство Component.
private void SetActive<T>(IEnumerable<T> collection, bool active) where T : Component
{
    foreach (T e in collection)
        e.gameObject.SetActive(active);
}

SetActive(_images, false);

Подобно тому, как class, который ни от кого явно не наследуется, наследуется от object, без явного указателя where, T тоже имеет object тип, у которого естественно нет свойства gameObject.

Но Generic ТУТ ВООБЩЕ НЕ НУЖЕН! В where обычно указывается не типы классов, а new(), struct, INumber и т.д. в то время как у тебя Image и Text с общим предок, свойство которого и используется.
private void SetActive(IEnumerable<Component> components, bool active) 
{
    foreach (Component c in components)
        c.gameObject.SetActive(active);
}


В случаях, когда используется List<T>, то можно воспользоваться методом ForEach.
_images.ForEach(i => i.gameObject.SetActive(false));


Метод надо дополнить скорее всего так:
private void Metod2 <T>(T[] all, int index) where T : UnityEngine.UIElementsModuleLeave {


}

По поводу UnityEngine.UIElementsModuleLeave надо уточнить в документации, от кого конкретно унаследованы Image и Text и подставить самый верхний уровень наследования туда

А вызывать надо так:
Metod2<Text>(textCollect, 111);

или
Metod2<Image>(imageBoxOpen, 111);


Спасибо большое буду пробовать.
